# How to edit resharper's action list

Tags: resharper

In Resharper I edited the inspection severity of the 'use var keyword when possible' to ''do not show'.

But when I select a certain word in the code file, Resharper still shows a pencil with an Action list in the left border with the action 'use var'.

Where can I edit the actions that should be shown? I cannot find this option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ReSharper > Options > Languages > C# > Context Actions and turn off 'Replaces var with explicit type declaration' action.

There are several lists next to each other (Right arrow), I didn't see them at first (rather unusual layout).

Comment: Hi Gerard, do you remember what you meant by there being 'several lists next to each other'?  I don't see anything matching that description in the options (R#7.0), maybe it has changed?  I don't want to miss out on features, though!  Cheers.

Comment: @ DGGenuine: sorry, I am currently not able to reproduce it because currently I do not use the Resharper.